# Android notification Reorder to front doesn't work. Copied from APP that it has worked in

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I've copied a code from dummy project testing Services and Notifications in which reoder to font worked like a charm.

Here is the code for notification (pretty same as in tutorials)

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle("Request awaiting")
    .setContentText("There is a service request awaiting for Your reaction");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);//stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    nBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = nBuilder.build();
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Manifest looks like :

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ld"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity 
        android:name="com.iraasta.cloudcab.driver.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

It looks exactly same in my other app, in which it perfectly brings app to front like when selecting from the home screen.
But in this one it calls OnCreate every time and loses whole state.

Comment: Does your app have a transparent/translucent theme?

Comment: It uses transparent styles on buttons with Android button bar style if that's what You're asking

Comment: There is a know bug that breaks the functionality of FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT if the activity has a transparent background. Maybe that isn't your problem. Since the Activity you are trying to launch is your root (LAUNCHER) activity, Why are you setting up the back stack here? There are no parent activities. Maybe this is causing the problem?

Comment: I just copied all of the code that is used in official android notification tutorial

Comment: And my app is single activity

Comment: If your app is a single activity, you don't need to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. It is already the front of its task.

Comment: So how do I just maximize app instead of restarting it while it's still running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bring your application to the front (if it is in the background) in whatever state it is in, or to launch your app (if it isn't aleady running), you need to launch your "root activity" (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) and set the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. This will launch the activity in a new task (if your app isn't already running), or bring the existing task to the foreground (if your app is already running).

Since you are doing this from a Notification, you should be setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in the `Intent` you pass to the Notification. However, Android is nice enough to set this flag for you if you forget to do it.

I'm not exactly sure why setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` caused your problem, but I can imagine that this somehow confuses Android.

Answer (score 1):

Not using any flag fixed it.

To people looking at this post in future.
If Your app uses single activity and You want to bring it to front after clicking the Notification just leave flags as integer 0.
It fixed my problem.
Thanks for suggestions

Bounty goes to the person that will explain why is this flag ruining everything.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in a manifest for an activity you wanna bring to the front works for me